# i suppose to recive random names and uppercase their first letter but when i put empty space in .split(' ') , my code breakdown

Tags: javascript, string, split

```
const capitalizeName = function (name) {
  const names = name.split(` `);
  const uppercasedName = [];

  for (const n of names) {
    //uppercasedName.push(n[0].toUpperCase() + n.slice(1));
    uppercasedName.push(n.replace(n[0], n[0].toUpperCase()));
  }
  console.log(uppercasedName.join(''));
};
capitalizeName('jessica ann smith davis ');
```

console shows the problem lies in upperName part  but when i remove space in name.split(' ') code will work but this time caps all the string letters

Comment: SHOW ERROR MESSAGE

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
capitalizeName('jessica ann smith davis ');
```

has a trailing space,

```
name.split(` `);
```

puts an empty element at the end of *names*

Either remove the space or trim before splitting:

```
const capitalizeName = function (name) {
    const names = name.trim().split(' ');
    const upperName = [];

    for (const n of names) {
        //upperName.push(n[0].toUpperCase() + n.slice(1));
        upperName.push(n.replace(n[0], n[0].toUpperCase()));
    }
    console.log(upperName.join(''));
};
capitalizeName('jessica ann smith davis ');
```

Edit: @jdkramhoft shows a third option in his answer: validating n inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is breaking because of the space at the end of `'jessica ann smith davis '` and works fine for `'jessica ann smith davis'`.

This is because split will identify the trailing space as an empty word. The easiest way to work around this with what you have would be to not attempt to uppercase undefined strings. If you want spaces between the final result you would join with a space character `join(' ')`:

```
const capitalizeName = function (name) {
  const names = name.split(` `);
  const upperName = [];

  for (const n of names) {
    n && upperName.push(n.replace(n[0], n[0].toUpperCase()));
  }
  return upperName.join(' ')
};
console.log(capitalizeName('jessica ann smith davis '));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing the bug its work fine now